# Stored data from server to local data sqlite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a recycler view and i get data from server , and its working good , the problem is when i tried to stored data from server to local data base using sqlite its not working , my question is can i stored the list directory to sql table ?? i tried to get string from list and stored it into local but its not working , this is my code hope anyone have idea tell me :)

```
 public void getRetrofitObject() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    Call<Result> call = service.getresults();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
            results = response.body().getResults();
            todoAdapter = new TodoRecyclerAdapter(this,results);
            todoRecyclerView.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
            for (int i = 0 ; i<results.size();i++) {
                 insert(response.body().getResults().get(i).getTODO_TITLE().toString(),response.body().getResults().get(i).getPriority().toString());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }});}
 public  void  insert (String x , String y )
{
    db.insertIntoDB(x,y);

}
```

and this is Sqlite insert method

```
 public void insertIntoDB(String Title,String Priority){
    Log.d("insert", "before insert");
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TODO_TITLE, Title);
    values.put(priority, Priority);
    db.insert(TODO_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

**Edit** 
when i tried to stored strings from server like this

```
   public void getRetrofitObject() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    Call<Result> call = service.getresults();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
            results = response.body().getResults();
            todoAdapter = new TodoRecyclerAdapter(this,results);
            todoRecyclerView.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
            for (int i = 0 ; i<results.size();i++) {

             String x =   results.get(i).getTODO_TITLE().toString(); //this 
                String y =   results.get(i).getPriority().toString();


                db.insertIntoDB(x,y);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }});}
```

i god this error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at com.example.todo.loginretroft.Activites.TodoList$3.onResponse(TodoList.java:151)
```

Comment: does priority equate to a column name? Should you perhaps have TODO_PRIORITY ?

Comment: yes , its same name , but i want to stored "result" list into local !

Comment: @MikeT please check my update

Answer (score 0):

before insert any data to database you should create the database :) 
Here is an good simple example - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

it will looks like this:

```
public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

    public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
}

    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}
```

}

Comment: thank you , i already create SQLiteOpenHelper  and its ok , but how to insert list into table?

Comment: do you have any error when you try to put content values to database? Did you create table for your values?

Comment: you can use Android Device Monitor and get database file from emulator\device and open it in any useful program like http://sqlitebrowser.org/
it can easy show you everything in your DB.

Comment: ok but when i run the app , the app is crash and give me the error !!

Comment: and also show please, whats going on in .getTODO_TITLE()